# Making a nested/hierarchical set of tables using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some data which I want to display in html tables using d3. My data is laid out like this:

```
var dataset = [
    {
        'name': 'foo',
        'children': [
            {
                'var1': 'hello',
                'var2': 87,
                ...
            },
            {...},
            {...}
        ]
    },
    {
        'name': 'bar',
        'children': [
            {
                'var1': 'howdy',
                ...
            },
            {...},
        ]
    },
    {
        // and so on...
    }
]
```

Ultimately, I would like to have something similar in style/functionality to [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025), where the user can click on the 'foo' row and see everything in the 'foo' group. But for now I'm struggling to display the data at all.

I've made a little [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EX3N4/3/) to show where I am now. As you can see, I have so far been unsuccessful at showing any of the actual numbers from my data. Does anyone have any ideas on how I should go about this? Should I restructure `dataset`? Thank you

== EDIT ==

I must apologise for maybe being vague about what I'm trying to do. Here is a [mock up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsafJ.jpg) of what I ultimately want to achieve, although I stress that this question is more about binding data than layout/transition stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your requirements correctly. Do you want basically something that puts HTML tables in the circles in the example you've linked to? If so, the easiest might be to create JSON in a similar style and modify that example.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I gave the example more for aesthetic reasons. Would that be possible though? To be honest, the code really confuses me, but I'll have a go at doing that.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible. I'm still not sure what you actually want to achieve. Could you maybe do a mockup?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff  see my edit for a mockup

Comment: Ok, I would suggest starting by creating the expanded version and then add any interactivity later. What you want to have a look at for this are [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/). You'll need more than 1 level of nesting like in the example, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do: http://jsfiddle.net/j43Nb/

Looking at your data, it seems more appropriate to have one table per parent and one row per child, and not wrap the whole thing in one big table.  If you really need one big table, just replace the div.section/h4 bits with another table/tr/td sequence.

The key to understanding how "child" objects become an array of cell data is in this bit at the end:

```
var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
    .data(function(d) {
        // return cell data as an array of prop values, 
        // ordered according to prop names in cols
        return cols.map(function(prop) {
            return d[prop];
        })
    });
```

where the field names in `cols` are used to build a corresponding array of cell values for each given row (child).

Comment: Thanks Ray! That's a massive help