# Binding data appears to be working, but nothing is being appended

Tags: d3.js

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929695/making-a-nested-hierarchical-set-of-tables-using-d3) which I asked last week (since then I've changed a lot of things though so don't pay toooo much attention to the code I posted).

My data is organised like this:

```
dataset = {
    'name': 'total',
    'groups': [
        {
            'name': 'foo',
            'children': [ {c1},{c2}...], // key: value pairings
            'totals': { key1: val1, ....} // where val1 = sum of key1 from all children
        },
        // and so on
    ]
}
```

What I'm doing in D3 is this:

1. Make a table for each group
2. Append a row for the group totals
3. Append th's for those keys not included in 'totals'
4. Append more th's for each item in 'totals'

   Then there is a function which adds the child rows/cells when the parent table is clicked

Item 4 is where I'm having trouble. Below are two scenarios which I have tried:

```
// (1) This works
parentTotals.selectAll('th.totals')
        .data(tbs) // tbs is a list of the key names in 'totals'
        .enter()
        .append('th')
            .attr('class', 'totals')
            .text(function(d) { return d; });

// (2) This does not work
parentTotals.selectAll('th.totals')
        .data(function(d) { return d.totals; }) // inherits a child from dataset.groups
        .enter()
        .append('th')
            .attr('class', 'totals')
            .text(function(d, i) { return d[tbs[i]]; });
```

The reason why I believe that the data is being bound correctly in scenario 2 is that if I put a `console.log(d.totals);` before `return d.totals;` I get a lovely `Object { key1: val1, .... }` for each member in the group. So if the data is being bound, why aren't any cells being appended? Thank you.

== EDIT ==

With the information provided by Scott I have made it work. If anyone's interested, this is what I did:

```
parentTotals.selectAll('th.totals')
            .data(function(d) { 
                return Object.keys(d.totals).map(function(k, i) {
                        return d.totals[tbs[i]];
                })
            })
            .enter()
            .append('th')
                .attr('class', function(d, i) { return tbs[i]; })
                .text(function(d, i) {
                    return (d/1000).toFixed(1);
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`totals` is an Object, not an Array. D3's data bind is based on arrays. You can get an array of key names from an object using:  `Object.keys(d.totals);`.